# Converting timestamps using strptime - R

Tags: arrays, r, date, time, strptime

I have input data with date and time stamps as `"140128142257"` which is the equivalent of `"14/01/28 14:22:57"` or `"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`.

I cannot get R to read this in so I can convert it to a usable date and timestamp. Any helpful advice would be appreciated.

Here is what I have tried:

`datetime    <- as.POSIXct(strptime(date[,2],format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`

However this just gives NA * length of array.

Comment: `%y` for two-digit year representation, `%Y` for four-digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uppercase `%Y` is used for four-digit years. You have to use `%y` for two-digit years.

```
strptime("140128142257", format = "%y%m%d%H%M%S")
# [1] "2014-01-28 14:22:57"
```